# Gentoo Linux - "emake" failed: No rule to make target '3'. Stop

Tags: gentoo, emerge, portage

I am trying to install Gentoo, where, according to the Handbook, says to update the world set. I get this (truncated for character limit):

```
pqueue.h => ../../include/openssl/pqueue.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/pqueue'
making links in crypto/ts...
make[2]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/ts'
ts.h => ../../include/openssl/ts.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/ts'
making links in crypto/srp...
make[2]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/srp'
srp.h => ../../include/openssl/srp.h
srptest.c => ../../test/srptest.c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/srp'
making links in crypto/cmac...
make[2]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/cmac'
cmac.h => ../../include/openssl/cmac.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto/cmac'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/crypto'
making links in ssl...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/ssl'
ssl.h => ../include/openssl/ssl.h
ssl2.h => ../include/openssl/ssl2.h
ssl3.h => ../include/openssl/ssl3.h
ssl23.h => ../include/openssl/ssl23.h
tls1.h => ../include/openssl/tls1.h
dtls1.h => ../include/openssl/dtls1.h
kssl.h => ../include/openssl/kssl.h
srtp.h => ../include/openssl/srtp.h
ssltest.c => ../test/ssltest.c
heartbeat_test.c => ../test/heartbeat_test.c
clienthellotest.c => ../test/clienthellotest.c
sslv2conftest.c => ../test/sslv2conftest.c
dtlstest.c => ../test/dtlstest.c
bad_dtls_test.c => ../test/bad_dtls_test.c
fatalerrtest.c => ../test/fatalerrtest.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/ssl'
making links in engines...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/engines'
making links in engines/ccgost...
make[2]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/engines/ccgost'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'links'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/engines/ccgost'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/engines'
making links in apps...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/apps'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'links'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/apps'
making links in test...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/test'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'links'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/test'
making links in tools...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'links'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/tools'
generating dummy tests (if needed)...
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/test'
md2test.c => dummytest.c
jpaketest.c => dummytest.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64/test'

Configured for linux-x86_64.

*** Because of configuration changes, you MUST do the following before
*** building:

    make depend
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q ...
 * abi_x86_64.amd64: running multilib-minimal_abi_src_compile
make 3 -j1 V=1 depend 
make: *** No rule to make target '3'.  Stop.
 * ERROR: dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q'

>>> Failed to emerge dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/temp/build.log'
 * Messages for package dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q:
 * ERROR: dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q-abi_x86_64.amd64'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2q/work/openssl-1.0.2q'
```

It says to post the output of `emerge --info` for support:

```
Portage 2.3.51 (python 3.6.5-final-0, default/linux/amd64/17.0, gcc-7.3.0, glibc-2.27-r6, 4.14.83-gentoo x86_64)
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-4.14.83-gentoo-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i5-6200U_CPU_@_2.30GHz-with-gentoo-2.6
KiB Mem:     1017488 total,     95996 free
KiB Swap:     524284 total,    508924 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 17:00:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: 55c839a863f2e4770b3762bd058e1144da1d7832
sh bash 4.4_p23-r1
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.30 p5) 2.30.0
app-shells/bash:          4.4_p23-r1::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:            5.26.2::gentoo
dev-lang/python:          2.7.15::gentoo, 3.6.5::gentoo
dev-util/pkgconfig:       0.29.2::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.6-r1::gentoo
sys-apps/openrc:          0.38.3-r1::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.13::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.69-r4::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:       1.16.1-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:       2.30-r4::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:            7.3.0-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:     2.0::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.6-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/make:           4.2.1-r4::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 4.14-r1::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.27-r6::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /usr/portage
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000
    sync-rsync-verify-metamanifest: yes
    sync-rsync-verify-jobs: 1
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 
    sync-rsync-verify-max-age: 24

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
ENV_UNSET="DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY GOBIN PERL5LIB PERL5OPT PERLPREFIX PERL_CORE PERL_MB_OPT PERL_MM_OPT XAUTHORITY XDG_CACHE_HOME XDG_CONFIG_HOME XDG_DATA_HOME XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
FCFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync multilib-strict news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync xattr"
FFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/gentoo-distfiles/ http://gentoo.mirrors.easynews.com/linux/gentoo/ https://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/gentoo/ http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/gentoo/ http://gentoo.cs.utah.edu/"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="3"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
USE="acl amd64 berkdb bzip2 cli crypt cxx dri fortran gdbm iconv ipv6 libtirpc multilib ncurses nls nptl openmp pam pcre readline seccomp ssl tcpd unicode xattr zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon sheets words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput keyboard mouse" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" NETBEANS_MODULES="apisupport cnd groovy gsf harness ide identity j2ee java mobility nb php profiler soa visualweb webcommon websvccommon xml" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-6 php7-1" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres9_5 postgres10" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_6" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby24" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="amdgpu fbdev intel nouveau radeon radeonsi vesa dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CC, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LANG, LC_ALL, LINGUAS, PORTAGE_BINHOST, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

Comment: Links to other pages that may disappear at any moment are discouraged.  If the links disappear, it would render the question completely useless and would not help future readers. Could you please include the important bits of the text linked to?

Comment: Sorry, @Kusalananda, the limit is 30000 characters, and with the output, it becomes 35425 characters. I truncated the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I did not set my make.conf file correctly. I did not follow the handbook, as I set `MAKEOPTS="3"` instead of `MAKEOPTS="-j2"`. Now that I set it to the latter, it worked.